# java sax parser mangles attributes for xml 1.1

Tags: java, xml, sax, xml-1.1

I'm using java's sax classes to parse an xml file.  If the xml file says version 1.0, everything works fine, but if it says version 1.1, then *some* of the attributes get mangled, giving me the wrong results but not throwing any kind of exception.

My xml file basically looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<gpx>
  <trk>
    <name>Name of the track</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="12.3456789" lon="1.2345678">
        <ele>1234</ele>
        <time>2013-03-26T12:34:56Z</time>
        <speed>0</speed>
      </trkpt>
      ... and then 419 further identical copies of this trkpt
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

So what I expect, when I use sax to parse this file, is to find 420 trkpt tags, and for each of them to have lat and lon attributes.  In particular, I expect to find 420 "lat" attributes which are all "12.3456789".

For the parsing I construct a handler object and give it the stream to this local file:

```
SAXParser saxParser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
saxParser.parse(inStream, handler);
System.out.println("done");
```

The handler class extends `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` and just has one method, `startElement` to react to the opening of the trkpt tag:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
{
    if (qName.equals("trkpt") && attributes != null
        && attributes.getLength() == 2
        && attributes.getValue(0).charAt(0) != '1')
    {
        // The trkpt tag has two attributes
        // but the value of the first one doesn't begin with '1'
        System.out.println(attributes.getQName(0) + " = " + attributes.getValue(0));
    }
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
}
```

So what is the result?
If the xml file has version 1.0, then all I see is "done".  420 trkpt tags were found, all of them had two attributes, the first one was always called "lat" and the value of this attribute always started with '1', as I expect.  Great!

If the xml file is changed to specify `version="1.1"` on the first line, then I get the following output:

```
lat = :34.56Z</t
lat = :56Z</time
done
```

So even though all my 420 points should be identical, two of them gave me a completely wrong attribute value.  No exceptions are thrown.  Still 420 trkpts were found, and all had two attributes called "lat" and "lon".  Oddly the lon values are always ok.

I created this xml file in a text editor by direct copy/pasting the first trkpt, so I'm sure that all the values are identical, I'm sure there are no points in the xml file with funny attribute values, and I'm sure that there are no non-ascii character values or entity codes or anything else odd about the file.

I've tried it using Sun's JRE6, OpenJDK6 and OpenJDK7, on three different machines with two different OSs.  So either I'm doing something wrong, or this particular xml file is incompatible with xml1.1 somehow, or there's a widespread sax bug (which seems unlikely as I would expect it to affect lots of people).  Again, please note, with xml1.0 it all works fine.  Also note, there's nothing special about the number 420, it's just that if the file only has 100 entries then they all get parsed properly.  If you have several thousand entries then a certain number of them get their first attribute value mangled in this way.  The length of the attribute value always seems to be correct but it's pulling characters out from the wrong point in the file.  Index overflow perhaps?

I tried removing all the speed tags, but the problem still persists if you have enough trkpts.  It's also sensitive to additional whitespace, so the problem occurs with different points or gives back different attribute values if I add line breaks between the trkpts.

Comment: This might be related: http://andrius.velykis.lt/2012/04/xml-11-long-attributes-in-java-6/

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the xml parser to me, which java version or which xml parser are you using? Also, the order of attributes is not defined by xml, it would be better to replace `attributes.getValue(0)` with `attributes.getValue("lat")`.

Comment: As I said, I'm using the JRE's built-in sax parsing and I've tried Sun6, OpenJDK6 and OpenJDK7.  And I don't care whether the first attribute is lat or lon, its value should still begin with '1'.

Comment: @Sami Korhonen, thanks for the link.  Yes it does sound like the same problem, I've just got lots of short attributes rather than a few long ones.  Unfortunately his solution is to use xml1.0, but I'd like to be able to read any file.

Comment: The solution is to use newer version of xerces (not the one bundled with your jre)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been present in the JDK XML parser for years, and neither Sun nor Oracle has showed any interest in fixing it. I strongly advise using the Apache Xerces XML parser in preference.

Comment: I tried searching for it but didn't find anything.  Is it reported on an official bug tracker or something?  Is it marked as wontfix?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I think I reported it at least five years ago but I've had trouble finding it in the tracker myself. But it's possible I never reported it, because you give up reporting bugs when you get no response. Anyway, it comes up every few months in a bug report that someone raises against Saxon, and the bug always goes away when they switch to using Apache Xerces.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried with Xerces and (so far) can't get it to fail in the same way.  So I think the best thing for me to do is to _attempt_ to use Xerces, and if that isn't available then fall back to the built-in sax parser (which works fine for xml 1.0).

Comment: @MichaelKay Could you please look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405840/xml-1-1-causing-nullpointerexception-when-used-in-xsd). Any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: My advice is simply, don't use the JDK parser, use Xerces from Apache.