# xml 1.1 causing NullPointerException when used in xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-1.1

I have an xsd file. I am trying to create `javax.xml.validation.Schema` using that xsd file. I have written a program that does it. When I use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` every thing works fine. But when I use `<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>` then the first attempt to create the `Schema` is throwing NPE but the second and subsequent attempts are successful. Below is the source:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

public class Test {
    SchemaFactory sf = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Test test = new Test();
        test.init();
        File schemaFile = new File("D:\\test.xsd");

        try {
            test.doIt(schemaFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("doIt() failed " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            test.doItAgain(schemaFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("doItAgain() failed " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Execution completed");

    }

    public void doIt(File schemaFile) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Schema schema = null;
        synchronized (sf) {
            schema = sf.newSchema(schemaFile);
        }
        System.out.println("doIt() success");
    }

    public void doItAgain(File schemaFile) throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Schema schema = null;

        synchronized (sf) {
            schema = sf.newSchema(schemaFile);
        }
        System.out.println("doAgainIt() success");
    }

    public void init() {
        sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    }
}
```

The method (`doIt()` or `doItAgain()`) executed first is throwing NPE.

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1738)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(XMLEntityScanner.java:1543)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:435)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:491)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:1802)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:531)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:519)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:485)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:210)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:594)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:610)
    at Test.doIt(Test.java:39)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

My question is,
Why XML 1.1 is not working properly?
Why only first attempt is unsuccessful?

Comment: could you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I use the latest versio of Xerces jar I dont face the isue. I also found that the problem is because there is a bug in JDK itself and its also logged at [openjdk website](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029437) and more interesting is that no one cared to fix this. So, use latest version of Xerces jar or use xml version 1.0. I will go with the first option. Who knows how many hidden surprises would be there in the old one :P

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727288/why-does-the-stax-parser-think-this-is-valid-xml-1-0-but-not-1-1) is some other guy facing similar kind of problem.